# Which plist in the iDevice is stocking the idevice's language?

Tags: ios, plist

i would like to know Which plist in the iDevice is stocking the idevice's language ?

I want to change the language of the ipad by changing the plist.

Do you know which plist it is ?

Thanks a lot !

have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been searching for the same thing. I came across the file /var/root/Library/Lockdown/data_ark.plist which contains com.apple.international-Language and com.apple.international-Locale. If you change the language on the phone, you can check the file and see that these properties are updated in the file. The problem is when I modify this file and restart the device, the language does not change and the plist file is overwritten. If you are able to figure it out, let me know.

**Update**

The above file is not necessary. The correct file to update is "/private/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist" This file contains an array called AppleLanguages. The array contains multiple strings for all the languages your device supports. Your default device language is Item 0 at the top. When you change the language, the file will be updated with the new language at the top of the list. So all you have to do is move the language you want to change to, to item 0 at the top of the list.